# Issue with Font through .ttf file

Tags: java, fonts

I Am loading a font through .ttf file in java but the size is coming as 1.
How to make it more like 16

```
InputStream in = Check.class.getResourceAsStream("CALIBRI.TTF");  
Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, in);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Font.deriveFont(Font, float)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#deriveFont%28int,%20float%29) to derive a font with the desired size from the newly created font.